# run vba in only one click

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I had given my sheet this code.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
  If Selection.Count = 1 Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D4")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Hello World"
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

But this only execute when after I exit from the cell D4. But I Want to execute the code as soon as I click on that cell only once.

Hope understand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very very small problem with your code. It is intended for the Workbook instead of the Worksheet. On the VBA editor, double-click on the worksheet that has D4, then enter the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Selection.Count = 1 Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D4")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Hello World"
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

When you enter D4, the message box with "Hello World" will be displayed.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother!

Comment: Dear bro, Can you solve this problem? https://superuser.com/q/1577380/1207783