# vba code for generating unique number in a column's cell serially

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, random-number-generator

I created a button in my excel sheet. Now I want that every time I click on that button an unique code will be generated in a cell. Again if I click on that button another unique code will be generated below the previous cell.

I tried `DEC2HEX` and `RANDBETWEEN` functions of excel. It works. But unable to find out how to make it functional with that button.

Hope understand!

Comment: record a macro of you using RANDBETWEEN, then copy the cell, and paste values, this is how I learnt VBA :)

Comment: don't understand bro. I am new to vba. Can you explain?

Comment: Didn't you ask this same question yesterday?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate unique code in another cell every time clicking on a button](https://superuser.com/questions/1576862/generate-unique-code-in-another-cell-every-time-clicking-on-a-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the VBA Editor, and enter the code below for your button

```
Sub Generate()

    Dim lRow As Long
    
    'Find the last non-blank cell in column A
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("G" & (lRow + 1)).Value = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 5000)
    'Select the last row of the column - Change the column
    ActiveSheet.Cells((lRow + 1), 1).Select

End Sub
```

Note that because you are using RANDBETWEEN function, Excel will recalculate the worksheet and change previously generated random numbers to new ones as stated [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/07/08/random-number-generator-excel/#blog-info-tile:%7E:text=Like%20RAND%2C%20Excel%27s%20RANDBETWEEN%20is%20a,integer%20every%20time%20your%20spreadsheet%20recalculates.):

> Like RAND, Excel's RANDBETWEEN is a volatile function and it returns a new random integer every time your spreadsheet recalculates.

Comment: all okay bro. But it is not jumping down one cell each time.Please check it.

Comment: @Mehedi See edit

Comment: Really helpful brother!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below macro to create a random number:

```
  Sub RandNumber()
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RANDBETWEEN(0,100)"
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End Sub
```

To create this as a macro Press ALT + F11, find your workbook in the navigator on the left, right click and insert a new module, then paste in the above.

Learn more on recording macors here:

https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-record-macro-microsoft-excel.cfm

You can edit the code above if you want your rand number to be between specific numbers and not just 0-100, i'll let you work out that part ;)

Comment: it helped but not fully. now it is generating unique code. But only on that cell which is active. But I want that at the first i click on the button, a code will generate in cell A1. Again if I click on that button, another code will be generated in A2. Again if I click on that button, another code will be generated in A3. Hope understand brother!

Comment: @Mehedi yeah ive added a new line in to jump down one cell each time